# "zlab" is not a graphical parameter

Tags: r

I have an existing r code that I need to modify. Currently, the code was used to plot a 2D(x,y) dataset. I need to update the code for a 3D (x,y,z) plot. Here is my code:

```
set.seed(1234567890)
nObs <- 100
ctrPos <- 3
xyzTmp <- matrix(rnorm(4*nObs),ncol=2)
xyzCtrsTmp <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1)*ctrPos,nObs*4,replace=TRUE),ncol=2)
xyzwidthTmp <- matrix(sample(c(-2,2)*ctrPos,nObs*4,replace=TRUE),ncol=2)
xyzTmp <- xyzTmp + xyzCtrsTmp + xyzwidthTmp 
gTmp <- paste0("class",(3+sign(apply(xyzCtrsTmp,1,prod)))/2)
  plot(xyzTmp,col=as.numeric(factor(gTmp)),pch=as.numeric(factor(gTmp)),xlab="X1",ylab="X2",zlab="X3")
```

abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)

I received an error code:

**"zlab" is not a graphical parameter"**

Is it possible to modify this code for a 3D plot?

Comment: `plot` doesn't do 3d, look into the [`scatterplot3d`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/index.html) package.

Comment: Thank you r2evans. I used scatterplot, and it worked.